# What is an example of a chi-squared distribution?

Tags: chi-squared-distribution

I'm trying to figure out the usage of the $\chi^2$ distribution. In other words, in what kind of situations it occurs and how is it useful in that situations.
I read the wikipedia definition of $\chi^2$. Can someone give an example of a $\chi^2$ distribution so that I can better understand it?

Comment: @Can't Tell: I think there is no rationale behind the chi-square distribution. You can see it as a sum of N(0,1)^2. You can also characterise it via its pdf. The reason why it is introduced is that important test statistics follow that distribution, at least approximately. For instance, the likelihood ratio.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks for your comment. But I'm not very good with statistics and I don't understand what you mean by sum of N(0,1)^2 or "likelihood ratio". What I was looking for was something like "if you take the case X, the variables Y and Z are independent standard normal random variables and if you plot the values A and B, then that would be a Chi Square distribution." Is such an example possible(with X,Y,Z,A and B)?

Comment: @Can't Tell. I am not sure to get what you exactly want. But take two **independent** standard normal random variables. Square them and add them. This results in a chi-square random variable whose parameter is 2. If you had had 3 normal variables, the parameter would have been 3, etc.

Comment: @Can't What does it mean to "understand" a distribution?  As it stands, this question seems rather personal and idiosyncratic in that regard.  Could you rephrase it so that it might be meaningful to other people?

Comment: @whuber: I edited the question. Do you think it is okay now?

Comment: @Can't Much better!  I hope it brings in helpful replies.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXB3cUGnaxQ) useful in finding the solution to my question.

Comment: This set of videos looks great. I [created a question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/introductory-statistics-video-courses) to popularise it and see if there are any other great quality video courses on introductory statistics.