# Introductory statistics video courses for social scientists

Tags: references, teaching

I have just discovered, through [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8232/understanding-chi-squared-distribution/8233#8233), a [nice video resource](http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy#grid/user/1328115D3D8A2566) to share with students in introductory statistics courses. The lectures, produced by the [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/#Statistics), are fairly didactic and well illustrated. I could not find the author of the videos.

Is there another set of video courses which I could recommend to my students, who are social scientists taking an introductory course in statistics?

The aforementioned set is software-independent and free to watch, two conditions that I need to maintain.

Comment: Did you look at this question, [Statistics/Probability Videos for Beginners](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/statistics-probability-videos-for-beginners), and the one that is linked to it?

Comment: @chl: No, I admit I had missed the [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/statistics-probability-videos-for-beginners/1763#1763) that already mentioned the Khan Academy material. But the other links are kind of unsatisfying to me because they seem recommended for specific audiences (life sciences, statisticians, Excel and R users) that deviate too far from mine. What I really like in the Khan Academy is the 'generic fit' of the lectures, and that is what I am now looking for elsewhere.

Comment: community wiki?

Comment: The author, of course, is Salman Khan.

Comment: [Their team](http://www.khanacademy.org/about/the-team) seems great.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.statisticslectures.com/ - I think, this is a really high quality resource. Explanations are clear, concise and very informative.

Answer (score 1):

IMO [*Statistical Rethinking*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus) is the way to go.
Some things he covers:

- Distinguishing statistical from causal modelling.
- Bayesian inference
- Monte Carlo methods
- Fundamentals of causal inference
- General(ized) linear models
- Categorical and ordinal variables in regression
- Multilevel models
- Gaussian processes
- Dynamic networks (e.g. social networks)
- Non-linear models
- Modelling measurement and classification error.
- Modelling missingness of data (i.e. model-driven imputation)
- Best practices

Answer (score 0):

The Udacity course :
**Introduction to Statistics (st101)
Making Decisions Based on Data **

Was really good. I learned a lot and it's focused on real world examples.

[Link](https://www.udacity.com/course/statistics--st095)

Comment: Other reactions to the course are actually [pretty negative](http://www.angrymath.com/2012/09/udacity-statistics-101.html), and I can understand why. I watched a few videos and was unimpressed.